# Can't save and read Rails variables in Rspec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I added ordering to my User model with

```
default_scope order: 'users.surname ASC'
```

Everything work fine.

Then I wanted to add a test case to my **spec/models/user_spec.rb** file.

Unfortunately, it gives errors. Although, there are similar tests, and they run fine.

Here are exerpts:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: 'Example', surname: 'User', email: 'user@example.com', 
    password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar') 
  end

  subject { @user }

  describe "remember token" do                                                                                                            
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) {should_not be_blank}
  end

  describe "users ordered by surname" do
    before do
      @user2 = User.create(name: 'Roy', surname: 'McAndy', email: 'pam@exam.com',
      password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar') 

      @user3 = User.create(name: 'Roy', surname: 'Andyman', email: 'pamjim@ex.com', 
      password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar')
    end

    pp User.all
    pp [@user3, @user2]

    User.all.should == [@user3, @user2]
  end

  describe "with role set to admin" do
    before do
      @user.save!
      @user.update_attribute(:role, "admin")
    end

    it { should be_admin }
  end
```

In above Rspec file, the **describe "users ordered by surname"** gives the following error:

```
bundle exec rspec
[]
[nil, nil]
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:32:in `fail_with': expected: [nil, nil] (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
 got: [] (using ==)
Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-[nil, nil]
+[]

from /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/operator_matcher.rb:56:in `fail_with_message'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/operator_matcher.rb:94:in `__delegate_operator'
```

I used pretty print (pp) for tracing purposes.

It is strange that in other cases **user.save!** works fine.

Where is my mistake, what could be wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not performing the operations of your test within an `it` block, but you should be.  e.g.:

```
  describe 'default scope' do
    before do
      @user2 = User.create(name: 'Roy', surname: 'McAndy', email: 'pam@exam.com',
      password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar') 

      @user3 = User.create(name: 'Roy', surname: 'Andyman', email: 'pamjim@ex.com', 
      password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar')
    end

    it 'should order by surname' do
      User.all.should == [@user3, @user2]
    end
  end
```